# Formal properties of Gaussian kernel smoother?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convolution, smooth-functions

Consider a continuous but not differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $Z$ a standard normal random variable. Define $g: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb R$ as the Gaussian kernel smoother $g(x,\epsilon) \equiv E[f(x + \epsilon \cdot Z)]$.

Are there known conditions on $f$ under which

1. $g(x,\epsilon)$ is well-defined?
2. $g(x,\epsilon)$ is differentiable in $x$?
3. $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{d}{dx} g(x,\epsilon)$ exists?

I think (1) just requires that $f$'s tails do not grow too quickly. (2) and (3) are intuitive to me, but I'm having trouble formalizing. Hoping to apply this in an economic model, using noise in a state variable's evolution to smooth out value functions of that state variable.

Comment: It seems like (3) requires something like $f$ Lipschitz continuous, in order to rule out examples like $f(x) = sgn(x) \sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: Also, Lipschitz continuity isn't sufficient for (3). Here is a counterexample: Imagine a continuous function $f$ which has $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ and, for $x > 0$, has $f'(x) = 1$ for $x$ between $1$ and $1/10$, $f'(x) = -1$ for $x$ between $1/10$ and $1/100$, $f'(x) = 1$ for $x$ between $1/100$ and $1/1000$, etc.